# Log4net event logging integration with Fellow Oak Dicom dicom.log4net

Tags: log4net, dicom, fo-dicom

I'm trying to use log4net to write to the Windows Event log. I'm using the [Fellow Oak DICOM log4net connector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/fo-dicom.log4net/)

I have setup log4net as I would in any service: the XmlConfigurator in AssemblyInfo, the *exe.logger is Copy to output, Copy Always. I have the nuget package Dicom.Log4net and the log4net package installed.

[After looking at the wiki](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/wiki/Logging-configuration), I've added

```
Dicom.Log.LogManager.SetImplementation(Dicom.Log.Log4NetManager.Instance);
```

Can I use my log4net xml config or would I need to initialize it like the Logging Serilog example?

Comment: I've found a work around and opened an issue on GitHub. The details of the workaround are in the issue.
https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/issues/244

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the failure to identify the `[XmlConfigurator]` attribute in the *AssemblyInfo.cs* file was due to insufficient initialization of the underlying *log4net* `LogManager`, see issue [#244](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/issues/244) and pull request [#248](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/pull/248).

As of April 12, 2016, this issue has been corrected in the *development* branch of *fo-dicom* and will be incorporated in the next release.

Comment: Thank you Anders for taking the time to investigate. This will really help and I look forward to the next version of fo-dicom! It's a great package.